# How to install and run Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, ide

How to install and run Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3 on Ubuntu 13.04? I followed the answer in [Installing Solaris Studio 12.2 in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541309/installing-solaris-studio-12-2-in-ubuntu) but i'm not understanding how to launch the ide.

Comment: Tanks this works for the executables.
How about the libraries (math performance libraries)?
How can you install them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps for installing Solaris Studio 12.3 on Ubuntu:

- Download [Tarfile](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen) on Linux x86 (390 MB)
- Move SolarisStudio12.3-linux-x86-bin.tar.bz2 to a work/scratch
  directory example `~/Install`
- `cd ~/Install; tar jxvf SolarisStudio12.3-linux-x86-bin.tar.bz2`
- Install the 32-bit (libc6, lib32gcc1,lib32stdc++6, etc.) libraries:

  `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
- `sudo mkdir /opt/oracle`
- `sudo mv ~/Install/SolarisStudio12.3-linux-x86-bin/solarisstudio12.3
  /opt/oracle/`.
- Add the executables (`/opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/bin`) to your path.

Hope that helps

For information and complete documentation, see the [Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3 Documentation page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/documentation/oss123-docs-1357739.html)

<sup>Source:Oracle Forums</sup>