# Installing Oracle Developer Studio on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, oracle

I'd like to Oracle developer studio (ODS) on Ubuntu (in order to use its advanced parallel debugging features), unfortunately the install script will only install on [Oracle Solaris, Oracle Linux or Redhat systems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/downloads/index.html). I've followed the advise in an [earlier post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329201/how-to-install-and-run-oracle-solaris-studio-12-3-on-ubuntu-13-04) but it doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest version of ODS. Short of installing a VM and then Redhat on the VM or another Linux installation I am at loss of what to do.

BTW, I don't mind using an older version of ODS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can install Oracle Developer Studio just by downloading the [tar file](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/downloads/developer-studio-12-6-tarfile-3778508.html) version and unzipping it. This method won't support updates via a package manager, but I was able to get it to work on Ubuntu 16.04. Once the tar file is downloaded it can be unziped with `tar`  and the program can be run by executing `./OracleDeveloperStudio12.6-linux-x86-bin/developerstudio12.6/bin/sunstudio`